# How to match a key and a value using regular expressions if the key and value can be swapped?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Let's say I have the following keys: `a, b, c` and I can have text like this:

> a 1 b 2 c 3

or

> 1 a 2 b 3 c

How can I write a regular expression that matches `b 2` in the first text and matches `2 b` in the second text? The idea is to return matches as keys and values no matter the order on which they appear in the text.

The main problem I've come so far is that when trying to look for a match in one order I will get false positives for the other order, so how can I solve this?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be as simple as this:

`(b 2|2 b)`

Link with example: https://regex101.com/r/ZnW96W/1

Comment: I mean, yes but the idea is to not hardcode the values, if you do (b \d|\d b) it gives a false positive for the first text